# Querying possible choices and existing transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this. My apologies in advance for the lengthy scenario and question.

I have three tables in SQL Server 2000: `Vendors`, `Imports`, and `ImportsStatus`.

Vendors send transactions each month, and when they are processed, a single record is created in Imports for all vendors, and a single record for EACH vendor is also created in the ImportsStatus table.

ImportsStatus is related to Imports on `ImportID`. 
Vendors is related to ImportsStatus on `ImportsStatus`.`VendorID` = `Vendors.ID`.

I'm trying to build a single select statement that I can create a view out of that shows a list of all possible vendors for each import regardless of whether the vendor has already been imported or not. Additionally, I want to show whether the entire import for a given ImportNo is completed. For example, for `ImportNo` 3, only `VendorIDs` 1 and 2 have been imported (and `VendorID` 2 is not even complete), but I would like to see `VendorID` 3 in the list as not completed as well because the `ImportDate` for `ImportNo` 2 is within `VendorID` 3's `StartDate` and `EndDate` interval (i.e. we should be expecting an Import for `VendorID` 3 that month). As well, I would like to see 0 next for each `VendorID` for `ImportNo` 3 showing that the import is not complete for all vendors for that `ImportNo`.

I have tinkered around with the query quite a bit (one reason being that I would start to see multiple entries for VendorID 1 because it is both in the Imports table for `ImportNo` 3 AND its `StartDate` and `EndDate` also surround ImportNo 3's `ImportDate`). I have finally come up with a query that looks and feels very clunky and wrong. I am hoping someone can help show me how I can optimize this query.

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE Vendors (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Imports (
    ImportNo INT NOT NULL,
    ImportDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE ImportsStatus (
    ImportNo INT NOT NULL,
    VendorID INT NOT NULL,
    UserName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DateProcessed DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Completed BIT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Vendors (Name, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('ABC', '1/1/1800', '9/9/9999')
INSERT INTO Vendors (Name, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('DEF', '12/1/15', '9/9/9999')
INSERT INTO Vendors (Name, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES ('GHI', '12/1/15', '9/9/9999')

INSERT INTO Imports (ImportNo, ImportDate) VALUES (1, '10/1/15')
INSERT INTO Imports (ImportNo, ImportDate) VALUES (2, '11/1/15')
INSERT INTO Imports (ImportNo, ImportDate) VALUES (3, '12/1/15')

INSERT INTO ImportsStatus (ImportNo, VendorID, UserName, DateProcessed, Completed) VALUES (1, 1, 'me', '10/5/15', 1)
INSERT INTO ImportsStatus (ImportNo, VendorID, UserName, DateProcessed, Completed) VALUES (2, 1, 'me', '11/6/15', 1)
INSERT INTO ImportsStatus (ImportNo, VendorID, UserName, DateProcessed, Completed) VALUES (3, 1, 'me', '12/4/15', 1)
INSERT INTO ImportsStatus (ImportNo, VendorID, UserName, DateProcessed, Completed) VALUES (3, 2, 'me', '12/5/15', 0)

-- Query that I want to optimize
SELECT ImportNo, ImportDate, CAST(MAX(CAST(Completed AS INT)) AS BIT) AS 

Completed, ID AS VendorID, Name,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vendors 
                  WHERE StartDate <= t.ImportDate AND EndDate > t.ImportDate) -
                 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vendors p INNER JOIN ImportsStatus s ON p.ID = s.VendorID
                  WHERE s.ImportNo = t.ImportNo AND s.Completed = 1) = 0 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
       END AS BatchCompleted
FROM
(
SELECT  CASE WHEN i.ImportNo IS NOT NULL THEN i.ImportNo ELSE
            (SELECT TOP 1 ImportNo FROM Imports 
                WHERE v.StartDate <= ImportDate AND v.EndDate >ImportDate)
        END AS ImportNo, 
        CASE WHEN i.ImportNo IS NOT NULL THEN i.ImportDate ELSE
            (SELECT TOP 1 ImportDate FROM Imports 
                WHERE v.StartDate <= ImportDate AND v.EndDate > ImportDate)
        END AS ImportDate,
        CASE WHEN i.ImportNo IS NOT NULL THEN s.Completed ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END AS Completed,
        v.ID,
        v.Name
FROM Vendors v
LEFT JOIN (ImportsStatus s INNER JOIN Imports i on s.ImportNo = i.ImportNo)
    ON s.VendorID = v.ID
    ) t
WHERE ImportNo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ImportNo, ImportDate, ID, Name
```

Comment: With query optimization questions you *may* have better luck on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) sites.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that as well, but I love SO so much that it is my go-to forum.

Comment: Do not cross-post on multiple sites.  Just decide on the one at a time.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up. I will keep it only on here for now.

Comment: I am trying to figure out one part of your question: you talk about showing whether the entire import is completed, but what does it mean to be completed?  Is there one row per vendor in vendors table?

Comment: I think you figured it out based on how you answered the question below, but basically, it means whether all possible vendors that are "active" during that time period have completed the import. And each row in the result set for that ImportNo would show either True or False (they would ALL either show True or False).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: In case you can't use the OVER clause on aggregate functions in 2000, the following should accomplish the same thing.  Sorry I missed the 2000 requirement, and unfortunately you need either a subquery or derived table.  The fastest way to accomplish this type of problem depends on the data, but I like to do the grouping on the key only in a derived table, and then join to that, which I believe becomes better performing for larger sets of data.

```
select i.ImportNo,
    i.ImportDate,
    coalesce(i_s.Completed, 0) as Completed,
    v.ID VendorID,
    v.Name,
    case when grp.Completed = grp.Total then 1
        else 0
    end as BatchCompleted
from Imports i
left join Vendors v on i.ImportDate between v.StartDate and v.EndDate
left join ImportsStatus i_s on i.ImportNo = i_s.ImportNo and v.ID = i_s.VendorID
join (select i.ImportNo,
        sum(cast(i_s.Completed as int)) Completed,
        count(v.ID) Total
    from Imports i
    left join Vendors v on i.ImportDate between v.StartDate and v.EndDate
    left join ImportsStatus i_s on i.ImportNo = i_s.ImportNo and v.ID = i_s.VendorID
    group by i.ImportNo
) grp on grp.ImportNo = i.ImportNo
```

I believe the following query might be an easier to read version of what you're looking for:

```
select i.ImportNo,
    i.ImportDate,
    coalesce(i_s.Completed, 0) as Completed,
    v.ID VendorID,
    v.Name,
    iif(sum(cast(i_s.Completed as int)) over (partition by i.ImportNo) = count(v.ID) over (partition by i.ImportNo), 1, 0) as BatchCompleted
from Imports i
left join Vendors v on i.ImportDate between v.StartDate and v.EndDate
left join ImportsStatus i_s on i.ImportNo = i_s.ImportNo and v.ID = i_s.VendorID
```

The idea here is to use partitioned sums/counts instead of subqueries to determine if the batch is completed or not.  It also uses `LEFT JOIN` to ensure each import is included.  I reordered and placed ImportsStatus at the end to prevent the duplicate problem you were having.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not at work at the moment and so cannot test it on the target SQL Server 2000 machine (I'm using 2012 at home). Will all the functions/operators such as coalesce, iif, and partitioning work in 2000?

Comment: I believe iif is new, so you might need to use a case statement instead: `case when sum(cast(i_s.Completed as int)) over (partition by i.ImportNo) = count(v.ID) over (partition by i.ImportNo) then 1 else 0 end as BatchCompleted`

Comment: Thanks! Doing a quick search leads me to believe that I may have trouble with partitions in 2000. Hopefully not. In any event, I marked as answered.